# how to set up Suave to access a post message on any route, and binding to "*"

Tags: f#, suave

I need to set up a service that need to accept POST messages to ANY route on that IP and have the web server listening to ALL IPs the machine has

I can make a list of local IPs easily, add 127.0.0.1 to it for testing.

How can I set up a callback on any post request, with the contents? I've just started to look at it 1h ago so the answer may be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will handle all POST requests sent to whatever bindings you'd like:

```
open Suave
open Suave.Filters
open Suave.Operators
open Suave.Successful

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

        // list your bindings here
    let bindings =
        [
            "127.0.0.1", 8080
            "127.0.0.1", 8081
        ] |> List.map (fun (addr, port) ->
            HttpBinding.createSimple HTTP addr port)
    let cfg =
        { defaultConfig with bindings = bindings }

        // handle all POST requests
    let app =
        POST >=> request (fun req ->
            OK $"POST received: {req.path}")

    startWebServer cfg app

    0
```

Powershell test: `Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://127.0.0.1:8081/Hello" -Method POST`

Output: `POST received: /Hello`